# how to set cursor position in gtk -Linux, MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, linux, gtk, monodevelop

Okay, so I thought I would get into Linux development. However, I found that you cant hardly manipulate the mouse and keyboard. My question is does GTK not support that sort of thing, or am I missing something?

In windows its easy:

```
Point Pos = new Point(20,20);
    Cursor.Position = Pos;
```

How would I do that in Linux?
I'm using MonoDevelop.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you mention using MonoDevelop on Linux, I assume you are using [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp). Using Gtk#, you need to use [Gdk.Display.WarpPointer](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGdk.Display.WarpPointer%28Gdk.Screen,System.Int32,System.Int32%29). Untested, but probably something like the following would work:

```
Gdk.Display.Default.WarpPointer(Gdk.Display.DefaultScreen, 20, 20);
```